# how do i connect my custom button board to pc via usb?

Tags: windows-10, usb, microchip

[image: button board]

**Goal/Challenge:**

i have a challenge to create a custom controller without using special controllers e.g. raspberry pi or Arduino.

**What i have done so far:**

I have created a custom board that takes power from the red wire and outputs power via the coloured strip depending on what buttons the user has pressed. 1= on, 0 = off, 9 outputs, 1 power input

**my problem:**

i am trying to connect this board to my pc via usb. 
I have seen that some chips can be used to do this but, i have no idea of what to use or how to connect them.

**Help/Info i need:**

what could i use to connect my button board to pc(windows 10) via usb?

**Extra:**

i don't know if i'm posting this in the right place or i'm using the right tags.
please suggest any changes i need to make

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make a custom button board the easiest way is to buy some buttons e.g arcade buttons und a zero delay usb encoder.
Plugs into pc via usb and work like any controller.. you can set the desired functions for each button via windows itself.